# ClaimsIdentity in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, owin, asp.net-identity

I am looking at the new bits of ASP.NET MVC 5 authentication, and noticed that everything now is a **ClaimsIdentity**. I was wondering where those values are stored:

Session, Cache, or in the Cookie itself.

If it is stored in the cookie, then there is an obvious limit to the # of claims you can store before exceeding the size limit of cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClaimsIdentity itself does not have a storage mechanism. But if you use the OWIN cookie middleware, yes it is stored in a cookie. And yes - there is a limit.

Comment: Bummer, so how do you handle roles that are coming from Active Directory, which could be 20 or 30 due to corporate environments? I guess you'd have to create a hybrid ClaimsIdentity that was somehow hooked to Active Directory?

Comment: You don't store them in the cookie?

Comment: Or use Windows authentication - this way you get a WindowsIdentity.

Comment: Aren't the roles added to the ClaimsIdentity. Every sample I've seen, adds the roles to the ClaimIdentity -> which gets pushed into the cookie right? Also I am build a Forms Auth that talks to AD, not Windows auth.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, the Claims from various sources can be persisted between sessions via a cookie created during the authentication process by default with OWIN. This is configured usually in \App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs. You can set things like when the cookie expires, whether you want a sliding expiration (cookie timeout is updated on return visits), where your authentication/authorization endpoint is, etc. The later part allows you to hook into providing additional Claims during the ClaimsPrincipal and ClaimsIdentity creation process. With a decent expiration, you only have to do this once for the users session. On subsequent trips back to your site, the OWIN middleware will parse the cookie and recreate all the claims from this step.

You shouldn't need to worry about cookie size and the new OWIN auth middleware implements cookie chunking (it's currently available from the pre-release sources - stable version does not chunk).

We've implemented this in our enterprise and we have several Claims sources: our internal single signon service, active directory, and our own application's database (for roles and additional properties about the user we care to track).

Answer (score 0):

So by default the MVC5 template generates the ClaimsIdentity from the database and persists this into a cookie form which is valid for a while.  But the user data is stored in a SQL database by default.

Comment: By default the domain data is stored in SQL Server, I understand that part, but when you go to create and feed the ClaimsIdentity object to the AuthenticationManager at that point it stores the same data into the cookie. If your data is too large for a cookie, then the cookie never gets written out to the browser because they will be rejected due to violating size constraints.

Comment: Yes the Owin CookieMiddleware takes care of turning the ClaimsIdentity into a cookie